# Price updater not working properly in FF, Opera and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

The described problem only occurs in FF and Chrome-Browser, other browsers like IE and Safari work fine. Opera used to work fine, too, but it doesn't now anymore, as I tested it a few minutes ago!

I'm using the shop-system **xtcModified-Version 1.06** with some Modules, like a tabbing-module and a price-updater-module.

Here's the code for the price-updater, where I think the problem is in:

```
var attributePriceUpdater;
(function ($) {
    // BEGIN: attributePriceUpdater
    attributePriceUpdater = {
        // BEGIN: calculate
        calculate: function (This) {
            var newPrice = 0;
            var summe = 0;
            var symbolLeft = '';
            var symbolRight = '';
            var data = This.data('attrdata');

            if ($('#optionen' + data.pid + ' select').length) {
                var el = ' option:selected'; //wenn selectfeld
            } else {
                var el = ' input:checked'; //wenn checkbox oder radio
            }

            $.each($('#optionen' + data.pid + el), function (index, item) {
                if (!$(this).parents('#optionen' + data.pid + ' [id^="pmatrix_v"]').attr('style')) {
                    data = $(this).data('attrdata');
                    if (data.aprice != 0) {
                        if (data.prefix == '-') {
                            summe -= data.aprice;
                        } else if (data.prefix == '+') {
                            summe += data.aprice;
                        } else if (data.prefix == '=') {
                            summe += data.aprice - data.gprice;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            newPrice = (summe + data.gprice).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/[.]/, ',');
            if (data.cleft) {
                symbolLeft = data.cleft + '&nbsp;';
            }
            if (data.cright) {
                symbolRight = '&nbsp;' + data.cright;
            }

            // html schreiben
            $('#optionen' + data.pid + ' .calculatePrice span.cuPrice').html(data.vpe + '&nbsp;' + symbolLeft + newPrice + symbolRight);
            $('div.product_price').html(symbolLeft + newPrice + symbolRight);
            // html schreiben
        },
        // END: calculate

        // BEGIN: calculateAll
        calculateAll: function () {
            $.each($('div[id^="optionen"] input[type=radio]:checked, div[id^="optionen"] input[type=checkbox], div[id^="optionen"] option'), function (index, item) {
                attributePriceUpdater.calculate($(this));
            });
        }
        // END: calculateAll
    };
    // END: attributePriceUpdater

    // BEGIN: $(document).ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
        attributePriceUpdater.calculateAll();
        $(".javascriptOff").css({
            display: "block"
        });

        $('#tabbed_product_info2 a[href]').on("click", function () {
            $('.cuPrice').css('background', 'red');
        });

        $('div[id^="optionen"] select').click(function () {
            attributePriceUpdater.calculate($('option', this));
        });

        $('div[id^="optionen"] input').click(function () {
            attributePriceUpdater.calculate($(this));
        });
    });
    // END: $(document).ready
})(jQuery);
```

I have made my problem available in **js-fiddle**...it "works" and shows the problem I've got, but the layout is wrong. But that does not harm the problem...

**http://jsfiddle.net/t2UW5/1/**

Normally the different dimensions should be arranged in tabs, in this example they are displayed one after each other.

Now to the problem:

The base-price of the article is 2,80 EUR.

I choose for example the first option at the price of 4,20 EUR. Now I scroll down to the end and the correct price gets displayed. Now I choose the last option "160 x 90 cm", and the price gets updated. But not to the correct price of 72,00 EUR, it displays 73,40 EUR.

First I've chosen the option at a price of 4,20 EUR. This minus the base-price of 2,80 EUR equals 1,40 EUR. That's the value the price is displayed including the new price (72,00 EUR + 1,40 EUR = 73,40 EUR).

When I click the same option a second time, the price gets displayed correctly at 72 EUR.

The same thing happens whenever I click another price in another tab, which can't be seen in this example as I described before).

Another example: first selecting the first option (4,20 EUR), then the 4th last option "118.9 x 84.1 cm" at 60,00 EUR. Updated price is displayed with 61,40 EUR, so again the difference between the base-price and the first selected option...

The absolutely strange thing about this is that the problem only occurs in Firefox, Opera  and Chrome-Browser!!! I tested the same site and the js-fiddle in IE and Safari, there it works fine!

I appreciate any kind of help on this! Thx in advance!

Comment: I just tried your jsfiddle in Chrome v28 on windows 7 and it displayed the correct price every time.

Comment: Hi RobH! Thx for looking at this...sorry, I think I interchanged Opera and Chrome...so it does not work in FF and Opera, But it's working in IE, Safari and Chrome on Win7!!! Sorry for that!

Comment: I added a 'console.log()' statement in the .each() which calculates summe and found that when the output was wrong, the .each() processed two elements with value 2,8.  I also note that some of the radio buttons have a different name= attribute, which allows more than one to be selected.  Hopefully this helps you track down the root of the problem and find a solution.

Comment: Hi dsh and thank you too for looking at my issue! The different name=attribute results of the different dimensions/formats that are offered. Those different id's are used to be placed in different tabs. So I don't think this has anything to do with the issue, because in the other browsers (IE and Safari) it works fine....can you tell me where/how you put this "console.log()", so maybe I can figure out something else with this?

Comment: I noticed that console.log(data.aprice) is getting called twice.  To replicate, click the last radio button and work your way up from the bottom and as soon as you get to 60,00 the data.aprice will fire twice inside the .each  One way to get the correct values is to add $(':radio').prop('checked', false); right before the Calculate function closes.

Comment: JS FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/t2UW5/3/

Yes, I know the radio buttons are not showing, but the correct number does show up.

Comment: Hello djrconcepts, and thank you too! I added the line "$(':radio').prop('checked', false);" to the script before the Calculate Funcion closes...now the price gets displayed correctly, when i select a radio-button in a different tab (like in this fiddle-example the 60,00 EUR). But the selection of the radio-button disappears immediately, so the user does not know which option he/she has chosen...when you click you can see the selection, but it disappears inbetween a second or less...hm...

Comment: if I change the code to `$(':radio').prop('checked', true);`, then the price gets updated correctly and the last radio button of each tab stays selected, but not the other ones...they still get deselected after chosing one of the radio-buttons.

Comment: sorry...it has to be `$(':radio').prop('checked', false);` as you wrote before, with `true` the price doesn't get updated correctly I found out after some tests...

Comment: Hey, Try this JS FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/t2UW5/4/
updated the input click function

$('div[id^="optionen"] input').on("click", function() {
            $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
            console.log('clicked an input');
            attributePriceUpdater.calculate($(this));
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JS FIDDLE.  Basically, on the click event the radio buttons are all deselected and then the one clicked is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/t2UW5/4/

```
$('div[id^="optionen"] input').on("click", function() {
    $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    console.log('clicked an input');
    attributePriceUpdater.calculate($(this));
});
```

Comment: Hi djrconcepts! 
Thank you very much for your help on this! This seems to work, but it leads into some other problems I didn't think of/realize before...but your solution seems to get me in the right direction! I'll keep trying based on your code! Thx again!